# How to do an if statement half of graph turns blank change it to return to numbers, error expected 2 got 0

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created code that calculates the maximum Lyapunov exponents against two parameters a and b. This plots ok, however there is a chunk of the graph that is white where the graph is collapsing due to my x and y values equalling zero. Therefore, I need to set these equal to say 100 or similar to prevent this from happening and producing a fully coloured meshgrid plot.

I have already tried if statements but I either get a syntax error or another error a.any() a.all() when I substitute one of these into my if statement it returns another error

```
#diff values of a and b looping 
a=np.linspace(0,6,80)
b=np.linspace(0,5,80)

def lyapunov(a,b):
    #initial conditions
    a,b = np.meshgrid(a,b)
    d = 0.1
    xold = 0.5
    yold = 0.01

    #xnew and ynew values
   for k in range(1000):
    xnew=f(a,b,xold,yold)
    ynew=g(b,d,xold,yold)
    xold = xnew
    yold = ynew

if np.any(xnew<ee) and np.any(ynew<ee):
    return 2.

elif np.any(xnew>ee) and np.any(ynew<ee):
    return 5.

else:
    xold = xnew            
    yold = ynew

    ml=0   
    for l in range(100):
        ydash=1
        ml = ml + np.log(abs(e(a,b,xold,yold,ydash)))

        ydash = yz(a,b,xold,yold,ydash) 
        xold=f(a,b,xold,yold)
        yold=g(b,d,xold,yold)


    ml = (ml/(2*100))
    return  ml

z = lyapunov(a,b)
ax.set_title('Lyapunov Exponent')
c = ax.pcolormesh(z)
fig.colorbar(c)
plt.show()
```

I expect a completed mesh grid with no white of colour showing the system collapsing and run time errors. At present only half the plot is coloured. ERROR is returning 'ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)'

Comment: hi Natalie, `f` and `g` are not defined to make this run-able and you have a syntax error at `if xnew=0:` -- this should be `if xnew==0:`.

Comment: should not `if xnew=0:` be `if xnew==0:` and `if ynew=0:` be `if ynew==0:`

Comment: Hi, I had to change it to if np.any(xnew==0): and np.any(ynew==0): to get no errors however the graph is looking the exact same. The half of plot is still white. I cant figure out why if I set ml to be a large number such as 100 when xnew and ynew =0